# Maintaining the position of columns in Grails/GORM

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Is there a way to fix the position of the columns in a domain? I have this domain:

```
class SnbrActVector {

    int nid
    String term
    double weight

    static mapping = {
        version false
        id(generator: 'assigned')
    }

    static constraints = {
        nid(blank:false)
        term(blank:false)
        weight(blank:false)
    }
}
```

This is the schema of the table generated:

```
CREATE TABLE  `fractor_grailsDEV`.`snbr_act_vector` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `weight` double NOT NULL,
  `term` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `nid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

It seems that the order of the columns were reversed. Is there a way to make it like this? (order is nid, term, weight)

```
CREATE TABLE  `fractor_grailsDEV`.`snbr_act_vector` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `nid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `term` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `weight` double NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Answer (score 3):

It's better not to rely on grails to create the tables for you, unless it's in-memory / for testing only. Use a tool, like [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/grails), to manage your schema.